# Verschieden vs. Unterschiedlich

Tags: standard-german

What is the difference between "Unterschiedlich" and "Verschieden"? From what I've gathered (from Stackexchange and Google more generally), there seems to be a subtle difference, but I've read no clear explanation as to what it is.

Comment: That question has already some answers here: [https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25539/ander-vs-unterschiedlich-vs-verschieden](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25539/ander-vs-unterschiedlich-vs-verschieden).

Comment: A duplicate question is not automatically a good reason for a downvote. I consider it a good question, which is why I voted it up _and_, at the same time, I flagged it as a possible duplicate.